# Are questions about blender forks such as "Bforartists"on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm moved to post a question here by [this question about the package "Bforartists"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/74726/599). At first superficial glance appears to be a shell over Blender. Should this be within the scope of Blender Stackexchange, or not? I'm prepared to vote to close, but I'd be more comfortable with some discussion of this first.

It seems to me, that if we're going to open BSE up to other forks, that we might want to add tags for the other forks, to better be able to distinguish posts related to a fork.

Comment: Related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/4/599. I think this could be an exception to that rule however, as being a fork, the differences may be more comparable less likely to be based on opinion.

Comment: I feel like this question just shows an inherent lack of research as a quick google search will explain what the differences are... because nobody would fork blender and just not change it...

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this question just shows an inherent lack of research; as a quick google search will explain what the differences are.

In fact, nobody would use a blender mod/fork/thing if it didn't do something better, cooler or faster.

The download page for any blender mod/fork/thing has almost always explained why you should use their software and I don't think that BSE is a place where "Google what this thing does for me please" questions should be accepted.

Comment: I agree that questions merely about the differences may be out of scope for BSE, and while the question that motivated my question here is one of these that shows a lack of research. But to the extent that these Blender forks can be thought of as a "shell" on top of a certain amount of actual Blender foundation code, I can see the possibility that questions from people using such a fork might be of more general interest to the greater community of Blenderheads. It seems to me that some questions are in scope, and others, mainly dealing with UI issues, are not.

Comment: Figuring out where to draw the line between questions about these products that are in scope, and those that are not, and how to publicize the existence and location of such a line seems better done as a conscious effort ahead of time, than ignoring the issue until another question comes up where the location of the line is an important consideration.